# How to validate cvs file header in apache Apache Commons CVS

Tags: java, apache-commons, fileparsing

I want to parse a CVS file using Apache Commons CVS. And there may be a scenario where user passed the wrong header row say 5 instead of 1. Is there any way to validate the header row passed to cvsParser if contains all Strings and not some other data type like Integer.